# Transferring Drive data to another domain

Tags: google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk, data-transfer

is it possible to transfer data from Google Drive (GSuite) from one organization to another using API calls? I have access to superuser accounts in both organizations
Example. Employee from company1 needs to transfer its Gdrive data to company2.

Answer (score 0):

If this is transferring data between G Suite accounts in Drive, you can follow the instructions:

> **Use the AP**I—To export and import documents, use the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/).
>
> **Download files**—Using Drive, your users can download files to their computer. Then, they can move the files to Drive in their new G Suite
>   account. See [Download a file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423534).
>
> **Share file**s—You can individually share files with people in your new account.
>
> **Transfer Drive files from a school Google Account**—Your users can copy
>   and transfer their Drive data from their school account to another
>   Google Account. See [Copy content from your school account to another
>   account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6386856).

If you transfer a lot of data at the same time, it might take some time to see the changes.